# Ejecting key, value from object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, kurento

I want to get the key, value of the recorderEndpoint from the object.

presenter[6] outputs undefined

```
presenter = {
    id : sessionId,
    pipeline : null,
    webRtcEndpoint : null,
    presenterRoomNum : roomNum,
    roomName : presenterRoomName,
    presenterId : presenterId,
    recorderEndpoint : {uri: argv.file_uri}
}
```

I want these results. {recorderEndpoint : {uri: argv.file_uri}}
What should I do?

Comment: try this `presenter.recorderEndpoint`

Comment: `Object.entries(presenter.recorderEndpoint)[0]`

Answer (score 3):

> hope this will help you

```js
let presenter = {
    id : 'sessionId',
    pipeline : null,
    webRtcEndpoint : null,
    presenterRoomNum : 'roomNum',
    roomName : 'presenterRoomName',
    presenterId : 'presenterId',
    recorderEndpoint : {uri: 'argv.file_uri'}
}

console.log(Object.entries( presenter))
```

Answer (score 0):

`presenter` is an object, not an array; you can't expect to index it by numbers.

The syntax you want is

```
presenter.recorderEndpoint
```

EDIT: based on the comment "I want these results. `{recorderEndpoint : {uri: argv.file_uri}}`":

```
x = {recorderEndpoint: presenter.recorderEndpoint}
```

Comment: I want these results. {recorderEndpoint : {uri: argv.file_uri}}

Comment: @sera Augmented my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use quotes

```
presenter["recorderEndpoint"]
```

Comment: I want these results. {recorderEndpoint : {uri: argv.file_uri}}

Comment: presenter.recorderEndpoint.uri, presenter.recorderEndpoint.file_uri